# Shard CSV based on time values

Tags: bash, csv

I have a 1 TB CSV file.  It looks like:

```
time,timezone,name,...
2020-01-09 04:05:12.23567,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:06:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:07:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:08:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:09:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:07:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 04:08:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 04:09:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 12:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 13:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 14:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 15:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 19:00:00.00000,-6,test2
```

I want to shard it such that the data is in `date-name.csv`, where `date` is UTC date.

In this example, I'd end up with

`2020-01-08-test1.csv`

```
time,timezone,name,...
2020-01-09 04:05:12.23567,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:06:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:07:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:08:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:09:00.00000,+8,test1
```

`2020-01-08-test2.csv`

```
time,timezone,name,...
2020-01-09 04:07:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 04:08:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 04:09:00.00000,+8,test2
```

`2020-01-09-test1.csv`

```
time,timezone,name,...
2020-01-09 12:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 13:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 14:00:00.00000,+0,test1
```

`2020-01-10-test2.csv`

```
time,timezone,name,...
2020-01-09 19:00:00.00000,-6,test2
```

The data set is huge, and the Python approaches I've taken are just too slow.  I'm hoping there's some more efficient way to do this with pipes and simple bash commands.

Comment: My naive mind tells me `awk '{ print > $1 "-test.csv" }'`. Why does `2020-01-10-test2.csv` has `test2` and not just `test`? What is the rule here? How are the filenames created? Is it important that the date is in UTC? Please post what have you tried, please post your python approach.

Comment: `test2` comes from the `name` column.

It is critical that the dates are UTC.

I unfortunately can't post the Python, but it loads in a few million rows at a time in Pandas, does the date operation, finds the unique date/name pairs, then writes to those files.

Comment: How slow is "too slow" ? How much ram/cpu do you have? HDD or SSD? How many unique dates do you end up with (tens, thousands, millions, ...)?

Comment: hi @ScottKennedy I have edited my reply. Now it should works https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682909/757714

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv --from input.csv put -q 'tee > strftime((strptime(($time."Z"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ"))-($timezone*60*60),"%Y-%m-%d")."-".$name.".csv", $*'
```

you will have

```
cat 2020-01-08-test1.csv

time,timezone,name
2020-01-09 04:05:12.23567,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:06:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:07:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:08:00.00000,+8,test1
2020-01-09 04:09:00.00000,+8,test1

cat 2020-01-08-test2.csv

time,timezone,name
2020-01-09 04:07:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 04:08:00.00000,+8,test2
2020-01-09 04:09:00.00000,+8,test2

cat 2020-01-09-test1.csv

time,timezone,name
2020-01-09 12:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 13:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 14:00:00.00000,+0,test1
2020-01-09 15:00:00.00000,+0,test1

cat 2020-01-10-test2.csv

time,timezone,name
2020-01-09 19:00:00.00000,-6,test2
```